# PYTHON - UDP listening without knowing the server

Tags: python, sockets, udp, listen

using python2.X (for Linux (++) and Windows (+))
I'm trying to create a python client, to listen to an adress and a port.
The messages are sent by an app on a specific adress and a specific port, but I don't know how it is written. I'm just sure it is functionnal and it uses UDP protocole.

So, I've written this code to receive the messages :

```
import socket
#---socket creation
connexion = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

#---Bind
try:
    connexion.bind(('', 10015))
except socket.error:
    print "connexion failed"
    connexion.close()
    sys.exit()   

#---testing
while 1:
    data, addr = connexion.recvfrom(1024)
    print "messages : ", data
```

At this point, there is no error running it, but the code stops at this line :

```
data, addr = connexion.recvfrom(1024)
```

and nothing happens... I think I'm not connected and can't receive messages but I don't know why.
I tried to change the adresse by : '192.168.X.X', but it's the same.

If anyone could help me, that would be great. I'm not very comfortable why python...
PS : sorry for my english.

Comment: It is not stopping at that line. It is waiting for the buffer of size 1024 to get filled up. It will return only when the buffer is full. Make sure that the sender is sending and try reducing the buffer size.

Comment: I think you are wrong. recvfrom waits for a packet, not for 1024 bytes. If the packet is smaller it will return with the data from the packet.

Comment: In the python documentation, it is said that the Buff size (1024) is the maximum amount of data to be received at once, so I was thinking like Steffen Ullrich

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. I changed the IP adress (in the documentation, it was 192.168. **00** 8. **0** 15 ; I tried whithout the zeros like a normal adress (192.168.8.15) and I received my messages

I changed the structure of my code too : (don't know if it has impact) I put my "try: [...] except:[...]" on the line

```
data, addr = connexion.recvfrom(1024)
```

instead of the line :

```
connexion.bind(('', 10015))
```

Thanks for helpping ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all well and fine. You can verify that it works using the following Python snippet:

```
import socket
connexion = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
connexion.sendto("sending data via udp", ("localhost", 10015))
```

If a message send with this snippet is not displayed, check your firewall. To investigate whether (or what) your other application is actually producing try using tcpdump or wireshark.

Comment: I didn't try this other way to check if it's ok. That's a good idea.
I'll try it as soon as possible